# Issue using matchedGeometryEffect animation in ScrollView

Tags: animation, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

Animating `View`s between a `LazyVGrid` and an `HStack` with another view in between them (in this case, a `Button`), using `matchedGeometryEffect`, works great:

[image]

*Note how the animating views move **above** the Done button.*

However, when the views are contained within a `ScrollView`, the animating views now move *behind* the intermediate view:

[image]

I've tried setting the `zIndex` of the `ScrollView`s to > 0 (or more) but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

**Person**

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
    var image: Image { Image(name) }
    
    static var all: [Person] {
        ["Joe", "Kamala", "Donald", "Mike"].map(Person.init)
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var people: [Person]
    @State private var selectedPeople: [Person] = []
    @Namespace var namespace

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                SelectedPeopleView(people: $selectedPeople, namespace: namespace) { person in
                    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 1)) {
                        selectPerson(person)
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.orange)
            }
            doneButton()
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                PeopleView(people: people, namespace: namespace) { person in
                    withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 1)) {
                        deselectPerson(person)
                    }
                }                
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }

    func selectPerson(_ person: Person) {
        _ = selectedPeople.firstIndex(of: person).map { selectedPeople.remove(at: $0)}
        people.append(person)
    }

    func deselectPerson(_ person: Person) {
        _ = people.firstIndex(of: person).map { people.remove(at: $0)}
        selectedPeople.append(person)
    }

    func doneButton() -> some View {
        Button("Done") {
        }
        .font(.title2)
        .accentColor(.white)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

**SelectedPeopleView**

```
struct SelectedPeopleView: View {

    @Binding var people: [Person]
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    let didSelect: (Person) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(people) { person in
                Button(action: { didSelect(person) } ) {
                    Text(person.name)
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.yellow.cornerRadius(6))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: person.id, in: namespace)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 80)
    }
}
```

**PeopleView**

```
struct PeopleView: View {

    let people: [Person]
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    let didSelect: (Person) -> Void

    let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(minimum: .leastNormalMagnitude, maximum: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)), count: 2)

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(people) { person in
                Button(action: { didSelect(person) }) {
                    person.image
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .layoutPriority(-1)
                        .clipped()
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                        .cornerRadius(6)
                }
                .zIndex(zIndex(for: person))
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: person.id, in: namespace)
            }
        }
    }

    func zIndex(for person: Person) -> Double {
        Double(people.firstIndex(of: person)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It seems to still be a problem! Very frustrating!

Comment: No - in fact I haven't done any SwiftUI since then… I was waiting for these kind of pain points to be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug in SwiftUI, because even if you put `Color.clear` of any height in place of and instead of your `doneButton` (or even `.padding` of some height for bottom `ScrollView`) the effect will be the same.

[image: demo]

As it is seen from view hierarchy there is nothing in between two `ScrollView` and rendering of images is performed in one single background view

[image: demo2]

Comment: Thanks - I found the same. Raised a bug with Apple (FB8458770)

Comment: Experience same issue on iOS 15.1 and swiftUI 3 :( is There any solution?